# Ecommerce shipping and billing address into one table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create an address form with shipping and billing address on same page.
When user gets ready for checkout , I want both shipping address form and billing address for to appear on same page. If billing address same as shipping address only record should be inserted into address table , if different two records has to be inserted and of course an update has to take place in orders table shipping_address_id,billing_address_id.

Having only one address model, how do I achieve two forms with one submit button.
Below is my model for address and orders

**I need some help in putting in controller also I'm trying to get a hash value for each billing and shipping**

Please help!!!

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,:first_name,:last_name,:address1,:address2,:city,:state,:zip,:phone,:billing_default,:      user_id,:billing_address, :shipping_address
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :billing_addresses, :class_name => "Order", :foreign_key => "billing_address_id" 
  has_many :shipping_addresses, :class_name => "Order", :foreign_key => "shipping_address_id"

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :order_no, :sales_tax, :shipping_fee,:total,:order_state,:gateway_type,:transaction_id,:transaction_status,:ip_address,:card_verification,:card_number,:billing_address_id,:shippin g_address_id,:first_name,:last_name,:user_id,:card_expires_on,:authenticity_token
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address"
  belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address"
  attr_accessor :card_number
  has_many :transactions, :through => :order_id
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :order_details
```

Comment: I'd advise a checkbox to "use billing as shipping" and if it's checked, duplicate the data...

Comment: Yes, I do have that and I'm handling that with a javascript. I'm trying to solve two forms and one table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a checkbox so the user can specify whether use the same billing and shipping address or type different ones.

In the form file you need to handle nested forms in the following way:

```
   = form_for @order do f 
     = f.fields_for :billing_address do |ba|                
       = ba.text_field :address1
       = ba.text_field:address2
       = ba.text_field :city
       = ba.text_field :state
       = ba.text_field :zip
       = ba.text_field :phone
     = f.fields_for :shipping_address do |sa|                
       = sa.text_field :address1
       = sa.text_field:address2
       = sa.text_field :city
       = sa.text_field :state
       = sa.text_field :zip
       = sa.text_field :phone
```

In your model don't forget to add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address
```

And probably need to add the autobuild to your address relations

```
belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address", autobuild: true
belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address", autobuild: true
```

In the controller create/update actions, you just need to check the checkbox value and assign them equal, here's one approach:

```
@order.shipping_address = @order.billing_address if params[:checkbox_use_same_address] == true
```

Answer (score 14):

This is a slightly complicated problem, you will find.

First, ask yourself: Do you really only want to insert one address if billing and shipping addresses are the same?

1. A customer wants to change the shipping address. You will need logic to create another address record and retain the original as billing.
2. Generally, avoid updates to billing and shipping addresses after an order is complete as they compromise data integrity. Once an order is closed, that's it; those addresses should be fixed. When an order requires a different shipping address, avoid having a dependency between it and the billing address.

Now, assuming you're going ahead.

### Using Nested Forms

Hide billing fields, and add a check box to your form that maps to an `order.bill_to_shipping_address`. Default it to checked. Show billing address if it gets unchecked.

```
  $('input[name="order[bill_to_shipping_address]"]').on 'click', ->
    if $(this).is ':checked'
      $('fieldset.billing_fields').hide()
    else
      $('fieldset.billing_fields').show()
```

In your order model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, reject_if: :bill_to_shipping_address
```

The draw back with this approach is, if there is a validation error, and the user happens to change his mind and bill to a different address, the billing form will not appear since it gets rejected.

### Use a Form Object

This might seem more complex, but it's a much cleaner solution.

[See 7 Patterns for refactoring ActiveRecord Objects](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/).

Build a form object as such. I've adopted this code from something I recently wrote for a Rails 4 app. Just reverse your relationships. In my case an order has one billing address and one shipping address; it does not belong to them.

```
class OrderForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Order")
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attr_accessor :params

  delegate :email, :bill_to_shipping_address, to: :order

  # Removed most fields for brevity
  delegate :name, :street, :street_number, to: :shipping_address, prefix: :shipping
  delegate :name, :street, :street_number, to: :billing_address,  prefix: :billing

  # Removed most fields for brevity    
  validates :email, length: { maximum: 60 }, email_format: true
  validates :shipping_name, :shipping_street, presence: true    
  validates :billing_name, presence: true, unless: -> { bill_to_shipping_address }

  def initialize(params = nil)
    @params = params
  end

  def submit
    populate
    if valid?
      order.save!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def order
    @order ||= Order.new
  end

  private

  def shipping_address
    @shipping_address ||= order.build_shipping_address
  end

  def billing_address
    @billing_address ||= order.build_billing_address
  end

  def populate
    order.email = params[:email]
    order.bill_to_shipping_address = params[:bill_to_shipping_address]

    shipping_address.name = params[:shipping_name]
    # etc...

    unless order.bill_to_shipping_address?
      billing_address.name = params[:billing_name]
      # etc...
    end
  end
end
```

Then from the controller:

```
  def new
    @order_form = OrderForm.new
  end

  def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(params[:order])
    if @order_form.submit
      # order saved, do whatever
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Your form now does not care about nested attributes and properties. It's nice a clean.

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.text_field :shipping_street
  = f.text_field :billing_street
  # etc...
```